# "require is not defined" in parcel React component library

Tags: javascript, parceljs

Error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index.js?5WdmUIncGTkIrWhONvlEDQ:1:1
(anonymous) @ index.js?5WdmUIncGTkIrWhONvlEDQ:1
```

First lines of index.js:

```
require("./index.css");
var $cI6W1$lodash = require("lodash");
var $cI6W1$react = require("react");
var $cI6W1$reactdom = require("react-dom");
var $cI6W1$swchelperslib_define_propertyjs = require("@swc/helpers/lib/_define_property.js");
var $cI6W1$chrononode = require("chrono-node");
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "stacks-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Components for Stacks CMS",
  "private": true,
  "main": "../public/js/index.js",
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel start app/index.jsx --host localhost --public-url /js",
    "build": "parcel build app/index.jsx --public-url /js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.8.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "postcss-modules": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@draft-js-plugins/editor": "^4.1.0",
    "@swc/helpers": "^0.4.14",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
    "chrono-node": "^2.3.8",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "dompurify": "^2.3.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draft-js-export-html": "^1.4.1",
    "draft-js-plugins-editor": "^3.0.0",
    "draggable": "^4.2.0",
    "dropzone": "^5.7.2",
    "linkify-html": "^3.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "openai": "^3.1.0",
    "parcel": "^2.8.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-datetime-picker": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.0",
    "react-fetch-component": "^7.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-sortablejs": "^2.0.11",
    "ress": "^2.0.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.24.4",
    "trix": "^1.2.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
  },
  "_id": "stacks-components@1.0.0"
}
```

a sample of app/index.jsx

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import DateRange from "./components/DateRange";
import DraftJS from "./components/DraftJS";
import Supertag from "./components/Supertag";
// ...


// Use this file to mount all the components defined in the components folder

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

function dateRangeInit() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".date-range-react").forEach((element) => {
    render(
      React.createElement(DateRange, {
        fromVal: element.dataset.fromval,
        fromFieldName: element.dataset.fromfieldname,
        fromLabel: element.dataset.fromlabel,
        toVal: element.dataset.toval,
        toFieldName: element.dataset.tofieldname,
        toLabel: element.dataset.tolabel,
        recordType: element.dataset.recordtype,
      }),
      element
    );
  });
}

dateRangeInit();
...
```

I am able to successfully build, and I can confirm that the JS and CSS files are being generated in the proper location. But the "require" error appears in the browser when I try to load the page.

I am seeing this error as I attempt to upgrade from Parcel 1 to 2. This error was not happening in Parcel 1.

My use case is that I have a Ruby on Rails web app, but I use Parcel to build some ReactJS components. The `index.js` and `index.css` file is loaded on each page in the Rails app.

Comment: can you post the entire actual error with its stack trace?

Comment: @Derek I've updated it thanks

Answer (score 0):

The outputFormat needed to be set to global so that it could be loaded as a "classic" script for my setup. See this documentation page for more information about the global format.

https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#outputformat