# Building a React component library with Parcel for use in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parceljs

I have an ASP.NET 6 MVC project. It started out as "just MVC front-end", i.e., all my views are in Razor inside the project itself. There is some small amount of vanilla Javascript for UI scripting.

At one point I decided that a certain part of the UI I was going to implement was too complex to slap some JS on top of the Razor-rendered HTML, so I wrote a React component for that. I added a function to `window` to encapsulate the `ReactDOM.render()` part and to pass some props as function arguments. The .js source files live in a folder with a `package.json` and a handmade WebPack script to bundle the source into a single file, that is published into `wwwroot/js` and loaded with a `script` tag. All is fine.

Now my React components are getting bigger, so I want to code them in TypeScript and use a better build pipeline. I've been using Parcel with good results and I thought its minimalist startup would be great in my scenario. So I started out a new "project" (a different folder with a new `package.json`) and set it up as a Parcel library, as described [in the docs](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/library/). I changed the output paths to send the built files straight to `wwwroot/js` just like I had with the basic React components. The build works, but when I launche the main MVC project and load the file in my page using a `script` tag, I encounter two different types of problem:

1. If I load the module script, I get an error that says `Failed to resolve module specifier "react/jsx-dev-runtime". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` It is clear to me why this happens (the module file starts out with `import {jsx as $3zECG$jsx} from "react/jsx-runtime";`), but I don't know how to fix that.
2. If I load the CommonJS script instead, it starts with a similar line, but it uses `require` and that is already an unknown function. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75923651/require-is-not-defined-in-parcel-react-component-library) and it makes me think that I shouldn't load the library with CommonJS.

**How can I use Parcel to build my React components library so that I can just load it into a traditional HTML page?**

**Before you ask**: a full-site React rewrite is out of question, since it requires to rewrite all the current logic into API endpoints. Also, it's a hobby project and I would rather use it to learn something new.